# Low cardinality column index VS table overheads

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, cardinality

I have a table which holds 70 thousand rows and it is planned to slowly grow to about 140 thousands within several months.

I have 4 columns with low cardinality that contain 0/1 values as in FALSE/TRUE. I have table overheads (after *optimization*) of 28 MB with table size of 6 MB. I have added 4 separate simple indexes to those 4 columns. My overheads dropped to 20 MB.

I understand that indexing low cardinality column (where there are many rows, but few distinct values) has almost no effect on performance of queries, yet my overheads dropped. And overheads increase without these indexes. Should I keep lower overheads or should I rather keep potentially pointless indexes? Which affect performance the most?

**P.S.** Table is mainly read with variable load ranging from thousands of queries per minute to hundreds of queries per day. Writes are mainly updates of these 4 boolean columns or one timestamp column.

Comment: Worrying about cardinality would be a micro-optimization at this point. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indices aren't pointless when you approach table sizes that have tens of millions of rows- and you will only see marginal improvements in query performance when dealing with the table size you are dealing with now.

You're better off leaving the indices the way they are, and reconsider your DB schema. A query shouldn't use 20+ MB of memory, and its performance will only snowball into much bigger problem as the DB grows.

That said, jumping from 70k rows to 150k rows is *not* a huge leap in your typical mysql database. If performance is already a concern, there is already a much larger problem at play here.  If you are storing large blobs in your DB, for example, you may be better off storing your data in a file, and save its location as a varchar field in your table.

One other thing to consider, if you absolutely have to keep your DB schema exactly the way it is, is to consider **partitioning** your data. You can typically partition your table by ID's or datetime, and see a considerable improvement in performance.

Comment: I could not find a proper "MySQL InnoDB overheads" definition. I thought it is how much extra data is stored on the disk besides the table data itself, such as cache and temporary indexes. Am I wrong? Are those 28 MB amount of memory queries use? I did partition tables not so long ago, performance did boost up (I now have this, primary, table and another one with less accessed data that is 17 MB in size).

Comment: You are correct! Here's a tip:Try doing an 'EXPLAIN EXTENDED' before one of these big queries to really see what's going on behind the scenes. Is this query doing a full table scan? Your next question on SO would undoubdtedly be what this stuff means, but it's important to know... One other thing to consider is if the data is being sorted first- ie. ORDER BY X DESC . Large data being sorted first will use the filesort engine in MYSQL, another memory killer. Good luck!